# UIImage not changing image because of EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash, why?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I have this conditional that results in a UIImageView being changed depending one what side a coined "flipped" (Int.rand(0...1). I am not sure why it is crashing at this particular spot, as before the program gets to this point it could change the exact same UIImageView with another image asset. The image asset I want to change it to does exist in the asset folder. It's just confusing why it is crashing at this particular instance.

```
func changeField(coin: Int){
    lowerField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    upperField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    firstP1.isHidden = true
    firstP2.isHidden = true
    
    if coin == 0{
        lowerField.image = UIImage(named: "Red_Attacker")
        upperField.image = UIImage(named: "Blue_Defender")
        
        if userSettings.float(forKey: "Timer_Slider") == 0{
            gameP1()
        }else{
            startTimer(slider_Value: userSettings.float(forKey: "Timer_Slider"), coin: coin)
        }
    }else{
        lowerField.image = UIImage(named: "Blue_Defender")
        upperField.image = UIImage(named: "Red_Attacker")
        
        if userSettings.float(forKey: "Timer_Slider") == 0{
            gameP2()
        }else{
            startTimer(slider_Value: userSettings.float(forKey: "Timer_Slider"), coin: coin)
        }
    }
}
```

[this shows where it specifically throws the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plcx7.png)

Anyone have any idea why it is crashing at this spot? Would appreciate the help!

Comment: maybe you are trying to update the UI not on main thread?

Comment: what is the main thread? Is it Thread 1? The error occurs in Thread 1

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that you have an image with this name
second thing try to put it in dispatchQueue:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                lowerField.image = UIImage(named: "Red_Attacker")
                upperField.image = UIImage(named: "Blue_Defender")
            }

DispatchQueue.main.async {
        lowerField.image = UIImage(named: "Blue_Defender")
        upperField.image = UIImage(named: "Red_Attacker")
}
```